# Returning the first pointer of a private array (edit)

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to learn C++ and OpenGL...

I want to return the first pointer of the array... but maintaing the const correctness...

it happened that:

```
   class Foo{
   private:
       GLubyte array[64][64][4];
   public:
       const GLubyte& get_array(){return array;}
   }
```

gives me this compiler error:

```
:28: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const GLubyte&' from expression of type 'GLubyte (*)[64][4]'
```

can you help me out in understanding how to return the <strike>const correctness</strike> first pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `const` correctness. If you want the first pointer... well, you need to return a pointer:

```
const GLubyte* get_array(){return (GLubyte*)array;}
```

The cast works because arrays are represented continuously in memory.

But i'm pretty sure a better solution to what you're trying to achieve can be devised with `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm want to pass the array to a OpenGL function... so a std::vector is not really an option... or am I wrong?

Comment: it werks! thank you! I thought that when `return array` it always gives the reference to the first pointer...

Comment: The `const` in this answer (in the return type) is optional. It may be bad design to return non-const from a public member, but I'm just restating.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with const correctness. You can't return an array of `GLubyte`s as if it was a single `GLubyte`. You would get the same error message if you removed the `const` and the `&` (except that the error message would no longer contain the `const` and the `&` either, of course).

Edit in response to your edit: If you want to return a *reference* to the first element, just return the first element: `return array[0][0][0];`. If you want to return a *pointer* to the first element, return the address of the first element (`return &array[0][0][0]`) and change the return type to `GLubyte*` instead of `GLubyte&`.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `array` is `GLubyte * * *`, so you cannot convert to a reference, the have to write

```
GLubyte const & get_array() const { return array[0][0][0]; }
```

so you get a reference to the first element of array. But if you want the pointer, you have to change your code as follow

```
GLubyte const * get_array() const { return &(array[0][0][0]); }
```

If you want something better for your C++ code, you can see also [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are after some sort of multi array wrapper then I think this might be close to what you are looking for

```
class Foo{
private:
    std::vector<GLubyte> array;
    size_t x_sz, y_sz, z_sz;
public:
     Foo(size_t x, size_t y=1, size_t z=1)
     :   array(x*y*z),
         x_sz(x), y_sz(y), z_sz(z)
     {}

     const GLubyte& element_at(size_t x, size_t y=0, size_t z=0) const
     {
         return array.at(z*y_sz*x_sz+y*x_sz+x);
     }

     GLubyte& element_at(size_t x, size_t y=0, size_t z=0)
     {
         return array.at(z*y_sz*x_sz+y*x_sz+x);
     }

     GLubyte *data()           //returns array
     {
         return &vector[0];
     }

     const GLubyte *data() const //returns const array
     {
         return &vector[0];
     }
};
```